# Fill frame proportionally many frames at once

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, alignment

So I have a layout of circle images like this:

[image]

Now suppose by `Data Merge`, I am able to generate the template with different pictures. The problem is, the pictures appear as above, so I want to be able to `Fill Frame Proportionally` all these images, for as you see, the generated layout composes of 300+ pictures, thus doing it manually is a hassle.

Is there such a thing like in `Illustrator` where you select similar objects, then do one action for all of them? So I could select all the circle frames with placed photos, and apply. `Fill Frame Proportionally`

Answer (score 1):

On the data merge panel go to the menu and select content placement options. There is a drop down menu called fitting. Here you can choose to fill frames proportionally. Its should fill frames during the data merge instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

Play with Object Styles:

- create a style that fits an image inside a shape. there are a number of fitting options as you will find out if you research this a bit
- apply this Object Style to all your circle shapes so when you import the pictures they will automatically fit the frame